# How do I have images resize and retain the ability to have them change on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have this issue.. I want to be able to use

```
.custom-forums {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-image-source:transparent url("../images/forums.png") center top no-
    repeat;
}
```

with

```
.custom-forums:hover {
   background-image: url('../images/forums-hover.png');
}
```

The issue is this: When `width` is set to `100%` it simply does not show the image. But when `width` and `height` are set to `170px` it does work. I would like to have the button resize based on screen resolution and retain the ability to have the hover image change.

Much gratitude,
Mas21

Comment: Do you have more code you could show? There are a number of reasons why it might not work. Even better if you could create a jsfiddle that reproduces you issue.

Comment: We need to see your HTML, but can it be that in the first case the height of your element is 0?

Comment: The height of the element is not zero. @tocqueville

Comment: Yes @JamieClark .. view the live site at https://sskyblock.com/

Answer (score 0):

Background images require a predefined height or content of a certain height in its container in order to work.

I had a thought you could do this another way:

- Use a background image
- Put another image in that div and on hover set it to opacity 0, or your preference and the bg image shows

Run this example:

```css
.container {
background: url('http://placehold.it/199x199') no-repeat center center;
width: 200px;
}

img {
transition: opacity ease-in-out .5s;
}

img:hover {
opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @MasonHerbel give it a try and let me know.